# How to convert a stream of objects with several attributes to a concatenated string

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert all attributes of a class to Strings in a certain format and concatenate them with a linefeed between them. I know that I could iterate over the list, convert the attributes of the elements to String etc... But I think there should be a nicer way to achieve my goal by using streams and lambdas, i just couldn't figure out how. If it should not be possible, just let me know.

Given the following Class:

```
public class LambdaTest {

    public LambdaTest(String a, int b) {
        setAttributeA(a);
        setAttributeB(b);
    }

        private String attributeA;
        private int attributeB;

    public String getAttributeA() {
        return attributeA;
    }

    public void setAttributeA(String attributeA) {
        this.attributeA = attributeA;
    }

    public int getAttributeB() {
        return attributeB;
    }

    public void setAttributeB(int attributeB) {
        this.attributeB = attributeB;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a nice way to transform a list in a way that it returns a String like this for the following objects:

```
LambdaTest lambdaTest1 = new LambdaTest("a", 1);
LambdaTest lambdaTest2 = new LambdaTest("b", 2);
List<LambdaTest> lambdaTests = Arrays.asList(new LambdaTest[] {lambdaTest1, lambdaTest2});
```

so that

```
"Lambda: A: a, B: 1 \nLambda: A: b, B: 2".equals(lambdaTests.magicLmabdaTransformation())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map your objects to a string and join them [with `Collectors::joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String result = lambdaTests.stream()
                           .map(l -> "Lambda: A: " + l.getA() + ", B: " + l.getB())
                           .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

It may make sense to define the string transformation in a `toString` method.